# What are the decision values at the margins in an SVM model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, svm, e1071

I am trying to show the decision surface of an SVM model and its margins in a 3D RGL graph in R. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266195/plot-svm-in-3-dimension) is a really nice, replicable example from stack overflow. I am using the same example:

```
library(e1071)
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)

n    = 100
nnew = 50

# Simulate some data
set.seed(12345)
group = sample(2, n, replace=T)
dat   = data.frame(group=factor(group), matrix(rnorm(n*3, rep(group, 
each=3)), ncol=3, byrow=T))

# Fit SVM
fit = svm(group ~ ., data=dat, kernel = "linear")

# Plot original data
plot3d(dat[,-1], col=dat$group)

# Get decision values for a new data grid
newdat.list = lapply(dat[,-1], function(x) seq(min(x), max(x), len=nnew))
newdat      = expand.grid(newdat.list)
newdat.pred = predict(fit, newdata=newdat, decision.values=T)
newdat.dv   = attr(newdat.pred, 'decision.values')
newdat.dv   = array(newdat.dv, dim=rep(nnew, 3))

# Fit/plot an isosurface to the decision boundary
contour3d(newdat.dv, level=0, x=newdat.list$X1, y=newdat.list$X2, 
z=newdat.list$X3, color="orange" add=T)
```

One can move the drawn surface around by adjusting the `level` argument. I created two additional semi-transparent margins at `level=-0.2` and `level=0.2`, with `alpha=0.1` for the semi-transparency:

```
contour3d(newdat.dv, level=-0.2, x=newdat.list$X1, y=newdat.list$X2, 
z=newdat.list$X3, add=T, color="gray", alpha=0.1)
contour3d(newdat.dv, level=0.2, x=newdat.list$X1, y=newdat.list$X2, 
z=newdat.list$X3, add=T, color="gray", alpha=0.1)
```

My semi-transparent margins now trace the points where the decision values are equal to -0.2 and 0.2 respectively. However, I chose these numbers arbitrarily, just to see if my code works. What would be the proper way of calculating the decision values exactly at the margins?

I am very new to machine learning and have no math or engineering background at all. I get completely lost in the formulas.

EDIT: To make my question a little more straightforward, I forced a linear kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common form of SVM (C-SVM) has the values at the margin as 1 and -1. Of course, due to numerical (in)stability, support vectors on the margin may not have precisely that value, but should within some small $\epsilon$.